# Why does zsh open at root directory "/"?

Tags: zsh, gnome-terminal, nixos

I'm using gnome-terminal with zsh on NixOs.

A fresh terminal window opens in the root directory "/". This is eventhough `$HOME` is correctly set to `/home/user`.

Next tabs opened in the same window are being opened in the same directory as the previous tab, which is expected due to some setting.

Why is it so? I want the initial tab to be opened in `$HOME`.

Comment: How did you configure zsh as your default shell?

Comment: What is the "some setting" you mention? If there is one previous tab (since it's the first tab), then it may be this setting that causes the initial shell to have the root directory as its working directory, possibly.  This seems plausible if the shell is using a variable that is initially empty, and later filled in for future invocations, somehow.  (Waving my hands...)

Comment: That is unlikely to have anything to do with the shell, or even the terminal emulators which don't change the working directory. zsh will inherit the working directory from the terminal emulator which itself will inherit from whatever started it.

Comment: @Kusalananda my mistae, I don't know the setting actually, I remembered incorrectly. 
With my previous system and zsh config the behaviour was to spawn new tabs in $HOME.
Now it's to spawn new tabs in the previous location. 
But I don't know which tool and setting manages that. At least in the zshrc config there doesn't seem to be a relevant difference.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I see. Then it's hard for me to tell what's in play. I am migrating my setup, from `Manjaro/gnome/gnome-terminal/zsh` to `Nixos/gnome/gnome-terminal/zsh` and I observe this difference in new tab behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I got confused by the gnome's switch from **gnome-terminal** to **gnome-console**. The two applications are almost indistinguishable, yet:

- console opens at root
- terminal opens at home and new tabs open where you configure them to, more configurability

EDIT: There is seemingly another difference elsewhere (See comments below)

Comment: On Arch Linux, GNOME Console opens in my home directory. I find it highly unlikely the GNOME people will default to opening it in the root directory, so I'd say something's wrong with your config

Comment: @muru are you certain it's gnome Console and not terminal? (if you type "ter" in the system search you will get both console and terminal in results)

Comment: Oh, it's definitely Console. I uninstalled Terminal a while ago.

Comment: Then I have no clue haha. Ill edit the solution above ^ but simply stick myself to gnome.terminal